# CodedUI In Console Application

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

Can we run the CodedUI Test Recorded on one system with visual Studio 2013 and run on another system with out the visual studio installed on it.
We have all the frameworks installed and copied the CodedUI Project and the Application

Answer (score 1):

You can, you should check out [this blog post(Running MStest without Visual Studio)](http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2013/05/running-mstest-without-visual-studio.html) or [Running test in MStest without installing VS IDE)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anutthara/archive/2009/12/16/running-tests-in-mstest-without-installing-the-vs-ide.aspx). It does require the TestAgent, you can download one of the ISO's [here(Visual Studio Agents)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1334).

These posts are not about Coded UI specifically so you should make sure you have a user logged in and unlocked when running the test.